# Node SHA-256 Base64 Digest

Tags: javascript, node.js, digest

I have a question about Node.js Crypto module's hash digest.

With the input `hello world` on the command line a base64 encoded sha256 produces:

```
$ echo -n "hello world"|shasum -a256|base64 -
Yjk0ZDI3Yjk5MzRkM2UwOGE1MmU1MmQ3ZGE3ZGFiZmFjNDg0ZWZlMzdhNTM4MGVlOTA4OGY3YWNlMmVmY2RlOSAgLQo=
```

Doing the same (as far as I know) on Node.js (0.12.9) produces an entirely different result:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var shasum = crypto.createHash("sha256"); 
shasum.update("hello world", "utf-8"); 
shasum.digest("base64");
// 'uU0nuZNNPgilLlLX2n2r+sSE7+N6U4DukIj3rOLvzek='
```

The hex digest procuced in Node and on the command line are identical (`b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9`). Why the difference in the base64 encoded digest?

Comment: Is the digest you're getting `b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9`?

Comment: @Joost the hex digest, yes.

Comment: Not making this an answer since I don't have time to test, but is it posible shasum -a256 outputs hex, then you are base64 encoding the hex? Your node.js example converts straight from binary to base64, and binary -> base64 will give different results that binary -> hex -> base64.

(EDIT: OK, turns out Git bash does come with these tools; I will make this an answer)

Comment: You edited the strings in your answer to use a capital `H`. I recommend you undo that edit, as it is very confusing in combination with the answers that still use `hello world` with a lowercase h (as well as the digest you are presenting).

Comment: @Joost good point. My original intention was to use 'Hello world'. The quick response time took me by surprise. I undid the edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the commandline example, you're encoding the string `b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9` as base64. The Node example encodes the bytes `0xb9, 0x4d, 0x27, 0xb9` *etc.* in base64. The two are quite different.

To see the difference, it might help to see what the hex string is, in bytes:

```
$ echo -n "hello world" | shasum -a256 | hexdump
0000000 3962 6434 3732 3962 3339 6434 6533 3830
0000010 3561 6532 3235 3764 6164 6437 6261 6166
0000020 3463 3438 6665 3365 6137 3335 3038 6565
0000030 3039 3838 3766 6361 3265 6665 6463 3965
```

That is quite different from the actual byte sequence `b9`, `4d`, `27`, `b9` *etc.*

**EDIT:**
In order to actually get the 'right' result on the command line, you could output an actual binary sha256 digest and encode that, instead:

```
$ echo -n "hello world"| openssl sha256 -binary | base64 -
uU0nuZNNPgilLlLX2n2r+sSE7+N6U4DukIj3rOLvzek=
```

Comment: So to produce identical results, I should base64 encode the sha256 hex digest?

Comment: Yes, that would produce identical results, but that's not the nice way. Sec, I'll update my answer.